# Call two distinct Azure AD protected APIs from Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

Setup:

- ASP.NET MVC5 application (Full Framework NET 4.7) with Azure AD on top
- WebAPI (Full Framework NET 4.7) with Azure AD on top
- .NET ADAL 3.x library (not MSAL) used in both apps

In the Web App, in Katana, the OWIN middleware:

- i authenticate the user (org account in a directory i control)
- i then exchange Authorization Code for Access Token 
  (with `resourceId: https://graph.microsoft.com`)
- i place the resulting Access Token in user claims

Now everything is fine and dandy, i can use the Access Token as Bearer and call Microsoft Graph and get `/me` user profile, picture and what not.

**But how do i call my own Azure AD protected API from my Web App?**

I can't just exchange the Authorization Code a second time for a different `resourceId`. I could `context.AcquireTokenAsync()` with `app_id` and `app_secret`, but the JWT i get back does not contain any **user** identifying claim, so now my API doesn't know anything about the calling user, it only knows that the confidential client (my Web App) did indeed present a valid token.

How do i request a token that will successfully call my API that will return some sort of user *claims*? The *user principal name* or *user id* is probably enough.

Should i just move all the Microsoft Graph calling logic to the WebAPI and exchange Authorization Code for my API's `resourceId`, or is there an in-place solution to my conundrum? What's the right pattern here? Ok not *right*, maybe just *better*.

Comment: Why can't you exchange the authz code a second time? Do you get some error?

Comment: Is that an OAuth2 thing, i mean is that a valid flow? I did try and got null exception from ADAL, but i could go back to the drawing board and try again if that's something that should be possible.

Comment: AFAIK it should be.. NRE from ADAL sounds pretty odd

Comment: Ok, so i do get an Access Token the second time i exchange Authorization Code, but the JWT has a GUID in the `aud` field (it's the app id of the API). This seems to trigger a 401 in the API. If my token has the usual `https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/webapiname` it works just fine.

Comment: Both should be valid audiences for your API :)

Comment: Yes, everything says it should work with the GUID as well. Really bizarre. Let me take a look at the middleware in my API maybe i screwed something up.

Comment: You have to configure them both as valid audiences in the API. Check that.

Comment: Right you are. Added both audiences to `TokenValidationParameters = {}` as `ValidAudiences = new [] { "https://blabla", "g-u-i-d" }` and it works like a dream. If you care to post an answer i will mark it accepted. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request for a second access token with the same authorization code for another API.

Depending on how you request the access token, the audience of the token might be either the client id or Application ID URI of the API. So you must make sure that both are accepted audiences in the API.

In the case of ASP.NET Core APIs, you can add the following in JWT Bearer authentication config:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudiences = new [] { "https://blabla", "g-u-i-d" }
}
```